# Missing Data Source Tab and Standard Control Tabs when design in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I cannot figure out how to recover the Data Source Tab and Standard Control Tab (if I remember the name correctly) when designing a Windows Form in VS 2013.

[image]

Do you know where I can get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View -> Other Windows -> Data sources

View -> Toolbars -> Standard